# onclick change image and open url

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I need an image to change when it's clicked and to load a URL without anything visual changing on the page.  I only need a total of two images and each image will be associated with one URL.  I was able to replicate the example of onclick image change located at:
http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/javascript/otherbasic1.php

For example:  I want the image of the earth to change to mars and load URL #1.  Then when mars is clicked on I want it to load back the picture of earth and load URL #2.  I want the URL to load in the background and not change the images of earth and mars.

**What do I add to the ".js" file below to accomplish this?**

```
var newsrc = "mars.jpg";

function changeImage() {
  if ( newsrc == "mars.jpg" ) {
    document.images["pic"].src = "/images/program/js/forms/mars.jpg";
    document.images["pic"].alt = "Mars";
    newsrc  = "earth.jpg";
  }
  else {
    document.images["pic"].src = "/images/program/js/forms/earth.jpg";
    document.images["pic"].alt = "Earth";
    newsrc  = "mars.jpg";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... The last time I've seen `document.images` collection used for this was in 90's. The question is a bit unclear, what do you mean with "_load a URL without anything visual changing_"? Looks like you'd need a link containing an image, and clicking on the image, you'd get a new page loaded, with a new image ..?

Comment: My goal is to have an image of my light in an ON an Off state and have that image change when it is clicked on.  There are a local web addresses that will turn the light ON or OFF from my ISY994i controller if a URL is typed in my web browser.  For on the URL is http://10.0.1.22/rest/nodes/20%209F%20A5%201/cmd/DON and for off it is http://10.0.1.22/rest/nodes/20%209F%20A5%201/cmd/DOF

Comment: I still don't get it. You can have a single document on a page at the time, from a single URL. Or do you have an iframe on the background?

Answer (score 0):

I used a boolean instead of testing strings but this should help you.

```
function loadCommand(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // if successfull
    } else {
      // if not successfull
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

var isOn = false;
var img = document.getElementById("pic");

// change handler
var loadImage = function() {
    if (isOn) {
        loadCommand("http://x.x.x.x/cmd/DOFF");
        img.src = "/images/program/js/forms/mars.jpg";
        img.alt = "Mars";
    } else {
        loadCommand("http://x.x.x.x/cmd/DON");
        img.src = "/images/program/js/forms/earth.jpg";
        img.alt = "Earth";
    }

};

// set up event handler
img.onclick = function() {
    // potentially send window to new location with window.location=<host>/cmd/DOFF or something similar
    // or just change state
    isOn = !isOn;

    loadImage();
};

// load initial image
loadImage();
```

Comment: How this code handles "_URL to load in the background_"? What ever that means ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Is this an error you see?  Are you asking how it loads the image?

Comment: No errors, the code is fine, but OP has an odd requirement of changing the URL too.

Comment: You can inspect the URL if you like, I will make a crude attempt to mimic what you are thinking of and change variable names .

Comment: Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Ugh, I think I finally get what you are asking for and have wasted our time.  You need to look at AJAX requests.  Search w3schools or google for them to figure out how to use.  jQuery provides a nice interface for this.  Sorry for not understanding the question at first.

Comment: I'm a little lost.  Is there any way you could plug both URLs into your example?  So when its the image of the Earth is clicked then the URL "http://10.0.1.22/rest/nodes/20%209F%20A5%201/cmd/DON" is loaded.  And then when Mars is clicked on 
"http://10.0.1.22/rest/nodes/20%209F%20A5%201/cmd/DOF" is loaded.

Comment: Well, you are trying to access a REST api.  You could technically just ask an iframe to open that but it would be a pain to know whether it was successful or not.  I have updated the example a little but its still very lacking in what you will eventually need, but you need to understand how to use AJAX and to handle success and failures.  Its obvious this is a hobby type thing and this may work for you but if you need more I would encourage more research as it would take a lot to bring you up to speed in a single answer.